# How to make bins of different sizes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bin

I have a list and want to make a column in a `DataFrame` that contains bins using `cut` or `qcut`, but issue is that my bins are not all equal size

```
l=[1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91,101, 126, 151, 176, 201, 226, 251, 276, 301, 326, 351, 376, 401, 426, 451, 476, 501, 551, 601, 651, 701, 751, 801, 851, 901, 951, 1001, 1051, 1101, 1151,1201, 1251, 1301, 1351, 1401, 1451, 1501, 1551, 1601, 1651,1701, 1751, 1801, 1851, 1901, 1951, 2001, 2051, 2101, 2151]
```

My desired output is as follows

```
+-----------+
|   Range   |
+-----------+
| 1-10      |
| 11-20     |
| 21-30     |
| 31-40     |
| 41-50     |
| 51-60     |
| 61-70     |
| 71-80     |
| 81-90     |
| 91-100    |
| 101-125   |
| 126-150   |
| 151-175   |
| 176-200   |
| 201-225   |
| 226-250   |
| 251-275   |
| 276-300   |
| 301-325   |
| 326-350   |
| 351-375   |
| 376-400   |
| 401-425   |
| 426-450   |
| 451-475   |
| 476-500   |
| 501-550   |
| 551-600   |
| 601-650   |
| 651-700   |
| 701-750   |
| 751-800   |
| 801-850   |
| 851-900   |
| 901-950   |
| 951-1000  |
| 1001-1050 |
| 1051-1100 |
| 1101-1150 |
| 1151-1200 |
| 1201-1250 |
| 1251-1300 |
| 1301-1350 |
| 1351-1400 |
| 1401-1450 |
| 1451-1500 |
| 1501-1550 |
| 1551-1600 |
| 1601-1650 |
| 1651-1700 |
| 1701-1750 |
| 1751-1800 |
| 1801-1850 |
| 1851-1900 |
| 1901-1950 |
| 1951-2000 |
| 2001-2050 |
| 2051-2100 |
| 2101-2150 |
| 2151-2200 |
+-----------+
```

so basically, I want to check if number exists within these ranges and then get values further column values based on a match.

Comment: i think you can just pass a list of the righthand values to cut or qcut ... not entirely sure offhand though

Comment: `pd.cut` do not need `equal size`. use `bin = l` in the `parameter` will be fine.

Comment: how do you determine the last bin size?

Comment: You can write a custom_cut

Comment: @anky, bin size are just given in an excel file trying to make my own using given data

Comment: @Ferris, i tried, but it gave an error

Comment: @Ferris, you were right missed x parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you start with this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(100*np.random.rand(100))
```

you can get the bins directly with:

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df[0], bins=l, include_lowest=True)
```

output:

```
            0       bins
0   77.386478   (71, 81]
1   97.008834  (91, 101]
2   37.207325   (31, 41]
3   62.065115   (61, 71]
4   37.533101   (31, 41]
..        ...        ...
95  93.900669  (91, 101]
96   9.734420    (1, 11]
97  15.910740   (11, 21]
98  58.655497   (51, 61]
99  91.975037  (91, 101]
```

Comment: this is good, but what if i want it to be dynamic, like next time list could be different

Comment: what do you mean?  Just do the same thing with new values for `bin_data` or `l`

Comment: but, i have to define bin_data dictionary everytime?

Comment: so, the list comes from a column headers and can change next time (value ranges), so now I am trying to make a range from these given values, do check my last question, the main problem is that one, but trying to come up with some lengthy solution .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079707/how-to-compare-numerical-values-to-categorical-ranges-in-column-headers-in-panda

Comment: I understand, but just want this bin_data dict to be created dynamically, no hard code,

Comment: I've updated my answer so to apply bins based on `l` to some other data.  If you are asking how to generate `l`, that is a separate question.

Comment: much better thanks, can you also look at my previous question? the main problem is that one

Comment: if you reformat it.  Please paste df.to_dict() instead of the markdown equivalent

Comment: updated my previous question, the desired output is the same, do note the columns headers of df2, these are the values I used in list `l` here in this question